# What is the balanced nuclear fusion equation?

Tags: energy, particle-physics, nuclear-physics, plasma-physics

Given that the deuterium-tritium (DT) reaction has been identified as the most efficient for fusion devices, what is the ultimate balanced nuclear fusion equation?

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: related question https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/407839/nuclear-fusion-requirements

Comment: On a related note, see the [Deuterium Cycle of Fusion](http://hyperphysics.phy-astr.gsu.edu/hbase/NucEne/fusion.html).

Answer (score 0):

The D-T fusion reaction is not the most efficient but it is "the easiest"
to obtain in machines on Earth.
The energy balance of the reaction is not chemical, but it is nuclear :

D + T   --->   alpha ( 3.52 MeV )  + neutron  ( 14.06 MeV )   ,  Q(DT)  =  17.58 MeV